# How to sort a list in libreoffc calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm working in libreoffc calc.. I have thousands of lines of data like given below:

```
Date            Name           Att. y/n
Employee :  Vinod                   n
20/02/2017                    PP    y
21/02/2017                    PP    y
22/02/2017                    PP    y
23/02/2017                    PP    y
24/02/2017                    PP    y
Employee :  Ganesh                  n
20/02/2017                    PP    y
21/02/2017                    PP    y
22/02/2017                    PP    y
23/02/2017                    PP    y
24/02/2017                    PP    y
```

There are 4 columns (Date,name,attendance and y/n). Now, everytime i have to drag the name column so that i can apply filter to it.. is there any formula which can help me to do it at once. Remember I have to drag vinod first 5 times and then Ganesh.

Please suggest appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to apply the name to every record that has that name so you can sort filter by name? If so, the easiest way would be to add a new column with the name beside each row that has employee data.

Assuming date is A, Name is B, Att. is C, y/n is D, then the new column will be E and the output will look like:

```
A           B       C       D       E
Date        Name    Att.    y/n 
Employee    Vinod           n       Vinod
20/02/2017          PP      y       Vinod
21/02/2017          PP      y       Vinod
22/02/2017          PP      y       Vinod
23/02/2017          PP      y       Vinod
24/02/2017          PP      y       Vinod
Employee    Ganesh          n       Ganesh
20/02/2017          PP      y       Ganesh
21/02/2017          PP      y       Ganesh
22/02/2017          PP      y       Ganesh
23/02/2017          PP      y       Ganesh
24/02/2017          PP      y       Ganesh
```

The formula to generate column E (assuming headers are row 1) is: =IF(B2="",E1,B2)
Fill down to the bottom of your data.

Note, in order to use this column for sorting, you need to highlight the whole column and copy then paste special->values into a new column F, at which time you can delete column E.